# Display name of a choice field in Django while using annotate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I am trying to get display names of choices when using annotate, but I haven't been able to figure out. I have the following query:

```
Survey.objects.values('what').annotate(count=Count('why')).order_by()
```

And the result is:

```
[{'count': 34, 'what': u'a'}, 
{'count': 39, 'what': u'c'}, 
{'count': 40, 'wat': u'p'}]
```

But I want something that displays the name of the choice field and not the key:

```
[{'count': 34, 'what': u'appreciative'}, 
{'count': 39, 'what': u'creative'}, 
{'count': 40, 'wat': u'promising'}]
```

I tried get_what_display (as mentioned on the docs and other stackoverflow answers on this topic), but django throws an error. i.e the following doesn't seem to work

```
Survey.objects.values('get_what_display').annotate(count=Count('why')).order_by()
```

Comment: `get_prop_display` is a property and not a database field. So you'll have to loop over it and update the display values AFAIK.

Answer (score 8):

To accomplish this without iterating over the queryset you can use a conditional expression to annotate with the display attribute. Annotated attributes are available to use in `.values()`.

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When

choices = dict(Survey._meta.get_field('what')[0].flatchoices)
whens = [When(what=k, then=Value(v)) for k, v in choices.items()]
survey_counts = (
    Survey.objects
    .annotate(get_what_display=Case(*whens, output_field=CharField()))
    .values('get_what_display')
    .annotate(count=Count('why'))
    .order_by()
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Building upon @bdoubleu's answer, I wrote the following generic conditional expression:

```
# myapp/utils.py
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When

class WithChoices(Case):
    def __init__(self, model, field, condition=None, then=None, **lookups):
        choices = dict(model._meta.get_field(field).flatchoices)
        whens = [When(**{field: k, 'then': Value(v)}) for k, v in choices.items()]
        return super().__init__(*whens, output_field=CharField())

# example usage
from myapp.utils import WithChoices
from myapp.models import MyModel
MyModel.objects.annotate(what_with_choices=WithChoices(MyModel, 'what')).values('what_with_choices')
```

There's probably a cleaner way to build that doesn't require passing the `model` arg to WithChoices but, hey, this works.

Comment: Hello, I've been using this as it seemed .. neat
However, using it with a related model doesn't work such as:

Model1.objects.annotate(f_display=WithChoices(Model1, 'f')) - OK
Model1.objects.annotate(r_display=WithChoices(Model2, 'r')) - ERROR

say that my Model1 has a foreignkey field to model2.. and model2 has choices... how do I get those choices?

Answer (score 4):

As it's said earlier, `get_FOO_display` is an instance method, not something that you can use in `.values()`. Thus, I'd go with Pythonic way to accomplish what you'd like to do:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

survey_counts = Survey.objects.values('what').annotate(count=Count('why')).order_by()

choices = dict(Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('what')[0].flatchoices)
for entry in survey_counts:
    entry['what'] = force_text(choices[entry['what']], strings_only=True)
```

Comment: Just small update for Django 1.10: `choices = dict(Survey._meta.get_field('what').flatchoices)`