# Django get total count of each choicefield in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Example model:

```
SOURCE_CHOICES = (
  'PH': 'PHONE',
  'OT': 'OTHERS
)
class Test(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(..., choices=SOURCE_CHOICES)
```

I am able to get to total count of each item in Model choice by using the following queryset:

```
Test.objects.values('source').annotate(Count('source'))
```

It gives me the following output:

```
<QuerySet [{'source': 'PH', 'lead_source__count': 5}, {'lead_source': 'OT', 'lead_source__count': 4}]>
```

Below is what I want to show in the template:

```
Phone: 5
Others: 4
```

How can I achieve this?

So far I have tried the following in the template:

```
{% for src in source %}
  {% for k, v in src.items %}
    {{v}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me the below output:

```
PH 5
OT 4
```

Comment: Please fix your source code. The syntax highlighting clearly shows a missing quote. It's very important to ensure that the code you show us accurately represents the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Please note: there are not other errors thrown by Django, I typed the code out so there could be mistakes, but I am looking for a solution to the end result I want to achieve.

Comment: It is _very important_ that your code accurately represent the problem you're asking about. How should we know which mistakes are relevant and which are irrelevant? Again, please [edit] your question and fix any errors that it main contain (at the very least there is the quote I mentioned before).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display name of a choice field in Django while using annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420867/display-name-of-a-choice-field-in-django-while-using-annotate)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience DTL gives you ability to access dict keys in the template like:

```
{% for src in source %}
    PHONE: {{src.source}}
    OTHERS: {{src.lead_source__count}}
{% endfor %}
```

other solution would be to implement template tag and use it accordingly, but the way I proposed above is more elegant and easy to use (IMHO). Hope it helps

Comment: As per your suggestion, nothing shows up in the template at all.